# Join 2 tables with known variable sorting by max(date)

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables transfers and equipment where there could be multiple transfers for each piece of equipment. I'm looking to join these 2 tables with a *`project id`* and return the latest transfer for each piece of equipment for a specific project.

```
transfers table:
tid, pid, eid, date

equipment table:
eid, ename
```

In my function I'm sending the variable `$pid` to sort out just the equipment transfers for a specific project id that is stored with the equipment id in the transfers table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirements may still be a little unclear to me, but to return only the latest "Transfer" & "Equipment" rows for a specific PID, perform the following:

```
SELECT t.tid, t.pid, t.eid, e.ename, t.date
  FROM transfers t
  JOIN equipment e ON t.eid = e.eid
 WHERE t.pid = ?
   AND t.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date) FROM transfers t2 WHERE t2.pid = ? )
```

Let me know if this does what you're hoping it will do.  If not, give me a little bit more information on the rows that would be in each of the tables.

Hope this helps,

john...

Comment: Not perfect, but it made sense enough to change it to get it to work. Here is my final code `SELECT t.tid, t.pid, t.eid, e.name, e.make, e.eqid, e.model, t.date
  FROM transfers t
  JOIN equipment e ON t.eid = e.eid
 WHERE t.pid = $pid
   AND t.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date) FROM transfers t2 WHERE t2.eid = e.eid )`

Answer (score 1):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   transfers NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   pid, eid, MAX(date) date
  FROM     transfers
  WHERE    pid = ?
  GROUP BY eid
) t JOIN equipment USING (eid)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had a similar query before but it's still returning all equipment transfers for each project. For instance, I transferred T40 truck to project NHS3 and then to project PLB 3 days later. The query outputs the T40 truck for both projects. I may not have been clear initially that it needs to output the current equipment on that job only.